# List of circles with css

Tags: html, css

I want to create an html/css list with css circles and text next to it (I don't want to use bullets for this).

What I am trying to accomplish is here: http://jsfiddle.net/EGGVF/

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
```

However, the circles appear on top of the list elements and not in line with them. How can I do this in a way that all is in line (bullet+circle+text)?

Comment: Can you please include the markup in the question too? This would make the question stand on its own instead of dependent on an external site.

Comment: Make `<p>` element inline-block instead of default (block).

Comment: hi kfk i could achieve what you wanted by removing <ul> and </ul> from the html file but it doesnt seems to be the right solution is it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left` in CSS.

```css
ul {
  list-type: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  /* use this */
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><span><a class="menu" href="#"></a>Test retest supertest megatest</span></li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu" href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and Span with padding / Margin..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

So many answers, but I still feel the need to post one that's a bit more comprehensive and simple. First up, here's the code I used:

```
<div class="left-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#"></a> <p>Test retest supertest megatest</p></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#"></a> <p>Test retest supertest megatest</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.left-menu .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-menu p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Things to note, in general:

- Use `border-radius: 50%` to get circles without needing to change it  when width or height changes;
- I got rid of everything not relevant to this question (fixed menu div, colors, etc);

Then, more specific to the question:

- Make sure children of the `li` don't linebreak and create their own line by avoiding `display: block` and setting `inline-block` for the `a` and `p`;
- Ensure the `a` and `p` vertically align using `vertical-align: middle`;

Now you're good to go. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AsMb/), or [one with some "debugging" info](http://jsfiddle.net/2AsMb/1/).

Answer (score 1):

**Just simply add this in your css style sheet, and your good to go !!**

and if you want, give some space between big circle and the text (padding)

```
 ul
 {
    list-style-type: none;
 }

 .menu{ 
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     width:1em;
     height:1em;
     border-radius:50px;
     color:#fff;
     background:#000;
     margin-right: 10px; // Add this if you want some space between text and circle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on the fiddle and will do the trick:

```
.menu { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore)  [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/TV3BH/)

> Summary
>
> ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the
>   element matched. Often used to add cosmetic content to an element, by
>   using the content property. This element is inline by default.

```
.menu:before {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using a media-object, you can search for it in google, what it is, one way of  solving the "media-object" problem is using a flex box.

Check out this [site](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)

```
.Media {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
}

.Media-figure {
   margin-right: 1em;
}

.Media-body {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Whilst the other answer is correct, this solution works on everything when you are suppose to do things like that.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGGVF/5/)